# Should I use independent samples t-test?

Tags: self-study, t-test, sample

I need to analyse if there's a difference between poor and rich European countries (using a GDP per capita index variable) and look if it has an effect on the variable environment.

The GDP per capita variable is a ratio variable going from 44-..., while the environment variable is a nominal variable with two categories (environment is important and environment isn't important). I was thinking about using the independent t-test since there's a scale variable and a nominal variable with two categories. What's your opinion?

If I read the question right, I need to know the effect of GDP (scale variable) on environment (nominal variable).

This environment variable is a recoded variable (before it was what is the most important thing for your country: economics, crime, health ...) so before I recoded it, it had 15 categories or so. So I decided to recode it in 2 categories those who thought that environment was the most important and those who didn't. There's also a Likert scale variable that I could use instead of this 'environment' variable, but I think it would be too difficult.

This is the GDP variable descriptive:

```
GDP_Capita_Index
----------------

       Frequency Percent Valid Percent Cumulative Percent Valid
  44,00        1.003         6,1         6,1          6,1  
  51,00        1.000         6,1         6,1         12,2  
  74,00        1.159         7,1         7,1         19,3  
  80,00        1.428         8,7         8,7         27,9  
  85,00        1.082         6,6         6,6         34,5  
 100,00        2.560        15,6        15,6         50,1  
 112,00          928         5,6         5,6         55,8  
 115,00        1.211         7,4         7,4         63,1  
 118,00        1.407         8,6         8,6         71,7  
 119,00        1.142         7,0         7,0         78,7  
 123,00        1.181         7,2         7,2         85,9  
 126,00        1.019         6,2         6,2         92,1  
 127,00        1.305         7,9         7,9        100,0  
 Total        16.425        100,0      100,0
```

Comment: Have you checked the assumptions for an independent t-test? Does GDP per capita have a normal distribution?

Comment: When checking the kurtosis and skewness, with environment being the dependent and GDP the independent, I don't think their normally distributed

Comment: The value 928 in the second column (to the right of 112,00) looks wrong. Please check. Also could you fix the column labels please to clarify what column of numbers has which label. (Avoid tabs as a separator though.)

Comment: Hosmer & Lemeshow do mention the use of this t-test as a quick way to *approximate* what the results of a logistic regression would be.

Comment: I've double checked the GDP descriptives, and the value 928 always pops up. If I use de indep. t-test wouldn't I see the effect of people thinking the environment is the most important issue on GDP, while I would need the opposite.